# StackApplet — Bringing Stack Exchange Notifications to Your Desktop [Large scale rewrite in progress]

Tags: app, notifier, windows, linux

> ### Rewrite In Progress
>
> I am currently in the process of completely rewriting this application from scratch. The code for the old version was an absolute disaster, written nearly four years ago when I first started learning Python. The new version will be written in Python 3 and use PyQt5.
>
> Unfortunately I don't have a timeline on this new version but a rough guess for an early release would be early July 2014. Eventually I hope to get an actual stable release ready for Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic) in October. Windows builds will be released when time permits.
>
> (I will also add a link to the project page on GitHub once I am a little bit further into this.)

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

StackApplet is a small status icon that sits in your desktop's notification area and alerts you to events that happen to your accounts. You will receive notifications about new answers, comments and reputation changes. All Stack Exchange sites are supported. The application is written in Python and the preferences page uses JavaScript.

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

Packages are available for the latest stable release (1.5.2):

- Microsoft Windows, get the [EXE installer](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download)
- [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)-based distributions, get the [DEB installer](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download)
- [Red Hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux)-based distributions, get the [RPM installer](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download)
- [Generic archive](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download)

#### Platform

Windows XP/Vista/7/8 **or** a Linux distribution with [PyGTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyGTK) installed.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com.

### Source

Available on [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_%28website%29): http://launchpad.net/stackapplet

Comment: The ultimate StackOverflow addict luxury. To see your reputation at all times.

Comment: Yup. It really helps me stay on top of my rep. Are you going to try it? I am eager to hear how it works.

Comment: You might want to use `f = open(os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"),"/.stackoverflow"),'r')` to open your settings.

Comment: @Flame: Thanks, man. I am completely new to Gnome desktop programming :) I'm assuming it worked alright, though?

Comment: George, would you mind if I 'borrowed' your stackoverflow icon? At least until there are "official" releases of icons/images?

Comment: @Nick: Sure. Help yourself.

Comment: works for me. pretty cool. I've gotta say though, its a little weird when it loads Jeff Atwood's stats on the first run.

Comment: @Chris: Well... it kind of has to display *something* when it first starts. Do you have any ideas of what would you like to see it display?

Comment: @George something simple like 'Configure User'. Should be easy to default to userid = 0 or -1 or null, and check for that at startup.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't support multiple instances (so I can track my rep on more than one site), otherwise great! :)

Comment: @Felix: Don't worry - I am planning to fix that :)

Comment: You now get notifications when comments are posted to you.

Comment: StackApplet worked very well for me for a week or so, but suddenly it started displaying "HTTP Error" and no matter what I do I can't get it to work again. It doesn't even show an icon. Is this something known?

Comment: @Peter: The API changed versions from 0.8 to 0.9 - You need to download the appropriate file again from the list above. All of the files above have been updated now and should work. If that still doesn't solve your problem, please let me know.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should have updated the version to 1.0.1 (or something like that) to indicate that it is a new version? :)

Comment: I don't want to give the wrong impression: thanks for a great app!!!

Comment: @Peter: No, **thank you** for the complement and giving me a heads-up on that. I do have a few more features planned still... :)

Comment: @George: May I suggest that you add a check box "Display user name". My user name takes up quite some space, and I already know it :) An SO icon and the rep 2 or 3 pixels after that is enough for me.

Comment: @Peter: Good suggestion. I'll try to add that soon.

Comment: @Peter: I made some pretty large-scale changes to it... please let me know what you think! (I will still add the feature to remove your username - don't worry.)

Comment: StackApplet fully supports the v1.0 API now.

Comment: @Peter: I added your option to it - you can now display reputation only!

Comment: @George: Sorry for the delay. It's wonderful!

Comment: Search for StackApplet in the Software Center turned up no results, but `sudo apt-get install stackapplet` worked fine. Odd.

Comment: @George Is it possible to install this without root privileges? We are here at the university running Karmic and we can only request package installs that are in the repositories...

Comment: @George, I installed to fedora 12 (2.6.32.16-141.fc12.x86_64) and my panel will not autohide now.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Peter You need root access to install packages.

Comment: @Peter: Well, it actually is in the Maverick repository right now. Would they let you install it from there?

Comment: @Chris: Weird. I just tried autohide and it works for me on Ubuntu 10.04. I have a VM with Fedora 11... I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Chris: I tried it in Fedora 11, but it seems to work okay in there too. Does your panel autohide when the applet is removed?

Comment: @George Yeah... it will take until june 2011 before we get that one here at university... :(

Comment: @George and @Chris I managed to install the sources in my home directory and set the bonobo path right. Working now!

Comment: @George Are you taking any patches? I think I would like to see things as automated related account fetching, notifying of answers on questions and favorites, links to the sites straight from the panel. Maybe I could contribute some features.

Comment: @Peter: I'm curious to know how you installed it to your home directory - I couldn't figure it out when I tried.

Comment: @Peter: As for the features you requested... I have actually implemented some of them... they just haven't made their way into the DEB yet. You can find the source code at http://launchpad.net/stackapplet as well as a place to file bugs / submit feature requests.

Comment: I'll maybe try to get the changes into my PPA later so you can try it.

Comment: @PeterSmit: I made a DEB available for 1.3rc1. The link is above.

Comment: I've just added the applet via ppa on my Maverick system. It sits so pretty on my panel. @George thank you!

Comment: Starring to install later, I'm excited now! :-)

Comment: I'd be great to make it multithreaded in Windows. It freezes a lot with my connection :(

Comment: @Oscar: Actually I'm in the process of doing that. Look for StackApplet 1.5 sometime before the summer (hopefully).

Comment: @Oscar: You can try the beta now - it's multithreaded.

Comment: It's not working for me on Windows XP SP3, the program won't even load. Help!

Comment: @Rodrigo: So the icon doesn't appear in the tray?

Comment: @George: Nope...I even tried installing Python 2.7.1 for Windows, but no go.

Comment: @George Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rod: Well... unfortunately I'm really not sure what could cause that. But I would certainly like to find out. If you are willing to try a debug version, we might be able to find out some more information. You can download it [here](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe). Then open a command window and type `'C:\Program Files\StackApplet\stackapplet.exe'`.

Comment: @George, ok...got the output, where do I send it? Thanks!

Comment: @Rod: Feel free to email it to me: `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`

Comment: @Rod: Perfect. I'll let you know when this gets fixed.

Comment: @Nunu: I may have this fixed now. Please download [this](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe) file and let me know if it works.

Comment: @George, will this work in Fedora 15 under the new Gnome 3? Is it in the repositories?

Comment: @rdr: It's not in the Fedora repositories, though it should work fine under Fedora with Gnome 3.

Comment: @George, wow! this app really works well in Fedora 15! Thanks!

Comment: @rdr: Great! I'm glad to hear that. I put a lot of effort into making sure it would run in just about any Linux distro.

Comment: Hey, did you see that Stack Applet is the top application by API usage? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/stack-exchange-api-usage-stats-and-api-2-0-plans/

Comment: @andrewsomething: No! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Have a nice new gold badge :) Now, could you make it work again? It's not working atm, and the reviews on the USC page confirm that

Comment: @Manishearth: Actually, the story gets a bit complicated here. The latest stable version (1.5.1) works just fine. The problem is that the latest version in the archives is 1.4 - which is old and broken. I'd love to get the latest version into the archives but it's something that a Debian maintainer has to do. I've talked to someone who said they would do it when they got a chance... but nothing's happened yet. In the meantime, you can install it from [my PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/george-edison).

Comment: Hmm, after installing it I ran it and there wasn't any visible change. (I'm on precise). I also navigated to the stackapplet folder and directly ran `python stackapplet.py`, but that just did nothing (without any error, and without giving me back the terminal). Any idea how I should run it?

Comment: That's odd. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What desktop environment are you running?

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/george-edison`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install stackapplet=1.5.1-0~201211040213~quantal1`
This works great for a brand new install of 12.10(QQ).

Comment: What about Mac version ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: Unfortunately I do not have a Mac and therefore cannot make and test packages for OS X. However, if you have Python and PyGTK installed, there's no reason a Mac user couldn't download the source code and build it.

Comment: Open a PayPall donations account and you will get money to bu a Mac with all the donations you will get for this great work.

Comment: For Mac OS X users there's a similar app: http://stackapps.com/q/3081/18656

Comment: The first set of links in your question are dead links (HTTP_404)

Comment: I get a "network error" for all my accounts, could this be a firewall problem? How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: @NathanOsborn: Question, is this ever going to be ported to OS X? I really think that this would be a useful addition to your app.

Comment: @RPi: I would honestly love to release a package for OS X but I don't have access to a Mac for testing. That being said, if you have GTK+ and PyGTK installed, it should run out-of-the-box.

Comment: @NathanOsman I have access to an old iBook G4 (mine) a 2008/2009 MacBook (my Mom's) and I could see if my friend could be help me test it on the new macs (they have 2 MacBook Pro's and the new iMac.) He also uses Stack Exchange, so I think that he wouldn't mind. I'll get GTK+ and PyGTK installed and test it!

Comment: @NathanOsman Is it possible to get chat notifications?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: No, but this is planned for a future release.

Comment: both links throw 404s. perhaps they can be indexed via wayback machine if you have copies laying around?

Comment: @NathanOsman Has the Ubuntu 1.6 version been released using the 2.x API? Because right now it is just giving `Unknown error` for everything.

Comment: @RPi Version 1.5.2 was just released and uses version 2.2 of the API. It's in the PPA and I think it got backported.

Comment: This app is AWESOME and very helpful!

Comment: May be it's just me, but it's not working for me on Ubuntu Mate(14.10). No site is showing up in add account popup. Screenshot with error in console: https://db.tt/Z1YukKcS

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: you must be using version 1.5.1, which uses a version of the API that no longer exists. You need to upgrade to version 1.5.2. You can find DEB packages [here](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download).

Comment: @NathanOsman Mine is 1.5.2 only: https://db.tt/JQnkaOph

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: that's strange. Version 1.5.2 doesn't use the URLs in your first screenshot. Where did you install it from?

Comment: I downloaded it from the same link you mentioned above: https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download

Comment: Software Center's screenshot: https://db.tt/A0VsYnoc

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: alright, that does appear to be a bug. I'll look into it.

Comment: I fixed it locally by using the new url and another minor change: https://db.tt/PZjCtCWQ :-). I also noticed the same url is used in [`stackapplet.py`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/stackapplet/1.5.2/view/head:/src/stackapplet.py#L162) as well, is that going to affect the app in any way?

Comment: I don't have notifications from the applet when someone post a comment or an answer. Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Does this still work ? Is it still being worked on ?

Answer (score 18):

Nice one!
But…

### Warning:

This notifier may be dangerous to epileptic users having rep like [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

;)

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As told in the related [Ubuntu Stack Exchange site question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18/monitor-your-reputation-and-get-notified-of-comments), it would be great to port it to use [app indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators).

Great app :)

Comment: I'll look into it and see what I can do.

Comment: This is scheduled for StackApplet 1.4 now.

Comment: This has now been completed.

Comment: This has now been released in StackApplet 1.4.

Comment: I think that it should go under messaging menu instead of having it's own icon.

Answer (score 8):

Not working for Windows (8x64)

Firstly, download links for latest 1.6 are dead

I've installed 1.5 and it doesn't show the list of sites

[image]

Find User even doesn't work.

And without the site list, even if I enter my userID it doesn't "Add Account"

Comment: Having the same issue, except on Ubuntu. Maybe it's something to do with the new API? I was having issues with the new API previously, but those were fixed...

Comment: Try installing 1.5.2. That fixed it for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Same here on Ubuntu 14.04.1 - is this an API change again?

Comment: Same problem, version 1.5.2, Ubuntu version 15.10.  I really want to use it, but can not.

Answer (score 6):

Not working for Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

I've installed 1.5.2 and it doesn't show the list of sites

[image]

Find User even doesn't work.

And without the site list, even if I enter my userID it doesn't "Add Account"

Comment: Same problem, version 1.5.2, Ubuntu version 15.10.  I really want to use it, but can not.

Answer (score 4):

I have StackApplet installed on my Ubuntu system (using the deb package [linked above](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/stackapplet/stackapplet_1.2.0_all.deb)). The About box says it is version 1.1 although the deb file name and package details both say it is version 1.2.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to update the numbers in the About box.

Comment: This appears to be fixed as of 1.3rc2.

Answer (score 4):

Is there any change to make this also work in [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) (for use in [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu))? I must admit that I have absolutely no idea about the technical differences of both desktops.

Comment: Well, this is the first Gnome applet I've written so I'm kinda new to applet development. Work will begin soon to port this to AppIndicators - that might work on Xubuntu. I don't know.

Comment: Please download the 1.4 beta mentioned above and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives) available for StackApplet?

And a feature request:

Ability to track "tagged questions" => "my filters". It’s cumbersome to refresh it all the time.

I haven't found an app which can do that.

Comment: There certainly is! You can find it here: https://launchpad.net/~stackapplet-dev/+archive/stackapplet That PPA is kept up to date with all of the latest changes to StackApplet.

Comment: updated my question with a feature request!

Comment: @freethinker: So what you're saying is that you want the application to notify you when a question with a given tag is asked?

Comment: Rather I want the applicaiton to notify when a question belonging to a filter is asked. I have created a few filters to track questions I'm interested in.

Comment: @freethinker: I see. Adding that feature is a possibility but it would be limited to the sites you already have added to StackApplet.

Comment: Thanks! Does the API already support filters? If it does, then it should give results across all stackexchange sites isn't it? Anyhow, it would be perfectly cool if it supports just the ones I have already added! That would be neat.

Comment: @freethinker: The current version of the API does not provide access to filters. There is reason to believe that the next version of the API will. In the meantime, version 1.6 of StackApplet will add support for tag notifications.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

At the moment a click on the widgets in the panel doesn't have a defined action. It might be handy to have a left click on a site widget open that site in the default browser.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try to do that soon.

Comment: I added that feature... you can try it out in the 1.3rc1 download listed above.

Comment: This has now been disabled in the 1.4 beta while some issues are worked out.

Comment: This is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

FYI I have fully finished the Launchpad translation into Russian. Could somebody [review](https://translations.launchpad.net/stackapplet/1.6/+pots/stackapplet-en/ru/+translate)?

<sub>(I haven't lived in Russia for 8 years and I am losing the language)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The 64 bit version tries to install itself in the Program Files (x86) folder. I am on win 7 64 bit on an Intel i5 processor. Since the filename reads amd64 I am assuming that I might as well install the 32 bit version, is this correct?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like a bug with the installer. I'll take a look into that when I get a chance - the 64-bit installer does install 64-bit executables though, regardless of where the files are installed.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, thanks, if you want, let me know and I will help you test it.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently become active on Arduino Beta SE and I wanted to have notifs for that on my desktop. However, StackApplet doesn't have that site in the addable (???) sites.

Is this a bug, as I know Beta sites can be added, I have Raspberry Pi working just fine; or is it just because Arduino hasn't been added to the list of sites somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to get this to work... I entered ubuntu.stackexchange and my username (russjr08) in the appropriate boxes, but it stays stuck on "Please Wait..." I even restarted Gnome-Panel

Comment: Sorry, there are two problems with what you are doing: first, you need to enter `askubuntu` in the site box instead of `ubuntu.stackexchange`. Also, you need to enter your user ID instead of your username. If you don't know your username, click the find button beside the user ID box.

Answer (score 2):

When I try to start it, I get an error message titled -

> stackapplet.exe - Entry Point Not Found

saying -

> The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic 
>   link library msvcrt.dll

What could be the reason behind this?

My platform is Windows XP Service Pack 2.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a bug that occurs when StackApplet is run on 64-bit versions of Windows. Rather than fixing this bug (which would have been a lot of work), StackApplet was recently rewritten from scratch to provide native support for 64-bit versions of Windows (among other things). You can find a native 64-bit installer for StackApplet 1.6 at the top of the question above. Please try that instead.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I am running 32-bit OS, not 64-bit....

Comment: Oh, sorry about that then. There is also a 32-bit installer for StackApplet 1.6. Does that work?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeEdison, I too am looking for the XP version. 1.5 didn't work for me. The link to the 1.6 32 bit version appears to be broken. It's reporting a "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /stackapplet/stackapplet_1.6_i686_setup.exe on this server." Do you have another link?

Comment: @BrianFenton: Sorry about that - for some unknown reason, the permissions on that file were set to `600` instead of `644`. I have fixed the permissions now, so you should be able to download the installer.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Hi George, works like a charm! Thank you so much for a wonderful app! :-)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Is it possible to configure the app to ignore some events (specifically reputation changes in my case, not really interested in them as much as the other ones)?

Comment: As of version 1.6 (currently in Alpha), only inbox items are included in notifications (so that would include answers to your questions, comments directed to you, and anything else you would see in your global inbox).

Comment: That was quick :). Thanks for the info, and for the great app (I especially like how it integrates with KDE's notification system) !

Comment: Excellent - glad to hear it's working for you.

Answer (score 2):

In version 1.6 alpha on Windows, the notification will often show

> **30 New Item(s)**
>   There are 30 new item(s) in your inbox.

when there are only a few items in my inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything similar for [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE_Software_Compilation)?

Comment: This application should run under KDE. That being said, I am considering rewriting this application in Qt - in which case the answer would be a definite "yes".

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Great. Hope to see an *alpha* from you soon.

Comment: There is now an alpha version available.

Answer (score 1):

The new 1.6 (32-bit) version won't allow me to "authorize" the app?!

I'm using [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista). I've looked, but I haven't found any help elsewhere? Any ideas?

PS: StackApplet is a great tool, so I’m keen to have it fixed. The 1.5 version works, but the 1.6 doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please describe what happens when you try to authorize the application?

Comment: I start the app. It loads. I right-click the icon. Move through the menus and click authorize. The authorize window pops ups. I click on authorize with google. It hangs indefinitely. Also, I tried other login methods and they all hang indefinitely too. It's the same whether or not I "use as admin".

Answer (score 1):

I installed it on Windows 7. On authorization, it threw up a bunch of dialogs about certificates missing, etc.

Once running, the only thing I could do was to look at my Inbox - there wasn't any list of sites or reputation.

I removed it for now, until more functionality is available.

Answer (score 0):

Can this applet show when there is new activity since the last visit like the envelope next to my username? In other words, if I don't see the notifications does it change colour or something to tell me I should visit the site?

Comment: That's a great idea... but how would it know you visited the site?

Comment: I don't know much about the API, so maybe it isn't supported. StackExchange has some way of determining when to change the envelope icon when there are new replies so I thought maybe that was available to applications using the API.

Comment: @moberly: No, I mean how would the app know that you had visited the page with your web browser? Suppose you get a message. The app turns green. You go to the site to see what the comment is... how does the app know that you did that?

Comment: I don't know how you would do that. That is, I'm not sure a new replies notification would work without cooperation from the StackExchange feature that provides that information. Presumably that would be via the API, but as I said I don't know much about the API.

All I know is that when I visit a StackExchange site there is a small icon next to my username that tells me if I have new replies (and how many). The thing is I have to individually visit each StackExchange site that I've joined to see it. I saw your app, and was hopeful it could also appear in my Gnome panel.

Comment: Of course, if there's no way for your app to determine if there are *new* replies, then maybe you could just show changes for the last 24 hours?

Comment: @moberly: Maybe this other thing that I made is what you're looking for: http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com

Comment: I don't think so. That is another website and it just appears to show aggregate information for all my linked accounts. I was just looking for a persistent indicator to remind me to go back to the Stack Exchange website because I'm not always at my computer. Kind of like the new email indicator.

Comment: @moberly: Well, I'll see what I can do. Would it work if your username kind-of flashed red until you clicked it when there was a new comment?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Yes, I wasn't looking for anything fancier than that. However, I don't think it needs to flash, just changing the background colour might be better.

Comment: @moberly: Now that the AppIndicators port is complete, the icon changes color when there are new messages. (Of course, this only works on Ubuntu.)

Comment: @moberly: This now works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to Appindicators I'd like to see this condensed to one icon which populates a dropdown list on click (but the libNotify messages are fine the way they are) Maybe something similar to the current messaging indicator?

Great app btw! It helps feed my addiction :)

Comment: Ya, I really haven't got around to experimenting with AppIndicators yet... but I'll try to make it as concise as possible. Also, I need to work a bit on getting my app to comply with the API throttle guidelines, otherwise you might see errors if you have a lot of sites going.

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version? (1.3rc1 at the moment)

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: I believe so - though the About still says 1.1

Comment: Oh. Well that was fixed a few hours ago :) 1.3rc2 is out now :)

Answer (score 0):

### Feature Request:

<s>Would it be possible to add a preference where I can point the app to an accounts page (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342852?tab=accounts)) and it automatically picks up all accounts from there? Possibly even monitor that page for new appearing accounts?</s>

Because it is rather tedious to enter all those accounts individually and it should be very easy to retrieve the data for the app.

BTW: thanks for writing the app!!

---

**Update**

Wait, I just noticed the "Check for associated accounts" preference in the current version, I guess that cancels out my request. Still:

1. Unfortunately the app does not check for duplicates (a duplicate being a two entries with equal site *and* user id)
2. it would be even nicer if the app could continually monitor the accounts and add new accounts automatically once they appear.

Comment: Hmmm... I like your idea. I'll see what I can do to implement it.

Comment: I'd have done it myself, but Python is *so* not my language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm installing Ubuntu 11.04; I saw StackApplet in the Accessories menu. It claims that as of the newly installed version 1.4, StackApplet is no longer a Gnome 2 applet, but instead it'll live in the tray area... except I'm not even sure Ubuntu 11.04's Unity will have a tray area to begin with. Kinda baffled by the coincidence.

At any rate, can you please consider improving the way the tray icon behaves? Currently it does nothing on right click and opens a menu in place on left click; if the tray bar is placed at the bottom of the screen, this puts the 'Quit' menu item squarely below where I clicked. Basically, clicking on the StackApplet icons closes it; I'd have to drag up to use the program itself.

Comment: Well, actually - StackApplet uses the [AppIndicator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) framework, so it'll work fine with future Ubuntu releases. As for the way the tray icon behaves, that too is unfortunately beyond my control since the menu is created and managed by the AppIndicator framework.

Answer (score 0):

Is there support for HTTP proxies?

Comment: Not at this point. Which platform are you using?

Comment: I'm stuck on Windows at work :'(

Comment: @George: Is there maybe a way I can modify some of the code to support proxies (at least hardcoded)?

Comment: Well, all of the HTTP code is in the file `stack_api.py`. This file is located in `/usr/share/stackapplet/`.

Comment: Hey @raphink, have you tried using Microsoft Firewall Client? I use it and all other apps on my PC don't require proxy setup, they just assume there's a direct connection to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I get the following warnings while installing your package in Ubuntu 11.04:

```
Lintian check results for /home/badp/Downloads/stackapplet_1.4.0_all.deb:
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/applications/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/applications/stackapplet.desktop 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_CA/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_CA/LC_MESSAGES/stackapplet.mo 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_GB/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/stackapplet.mo 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/es/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/stackapplet.mo 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/fr/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/stackapplet.mo 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/tr/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/locale/tr/LC_MESSAGES/stackapplet.mo 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/meta.stackoverflow.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/serverfault.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet_grey.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/stackapplet_light.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/stackapps.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/stackoverflow.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/pixmaps/superuser.png 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/ 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/appindicator_replacement.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/config_store.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/import_13.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/prefs_dialog.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/select_user.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/stack_api.py 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.glade 1000/1000
E: StackApplet: wrong-file-owner-uid-or-gid usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py 1000/1000
```

Comment: That's due to Natty's new 'bad quality package' warnings. If you want to install the package anyway, rest assured that installing StackApplet is completely safe. If not, StackApplet 1.5 will have these warnings fixed.

Comment: @George I installed it anyway; just letting you know :)

Answer (score 0):

This neither works in Windows XP nor in [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) 6 for me.  What could be wrong?  Nothing happens when I try to launch...

```
peter@debian-peter:~$ python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py", line 116, in <module>
        import preferences     # a web server that allows preferences to be changed
      File "/usr/share/stackapplet/preferences.py", line 289, in <module>
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 8140), preference_server)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 402, in __init__
        self.server_bind()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 413, in server_bind
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
      File "<string>", line 1, in bind
    socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
    peter@debian-peter:~$ python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py", line 116, in <module>
        import preferences     # a web server that allows preferences to be changed
      File "/usr/share/stackapplet/preferences.py", line 364, in <module>
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', 8140), preference_server)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 402, in __init__
        self.server_bind()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 413, in server_bind
        self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
      File "<string>", line 1, in bind
    socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work in Windows XP, but it's easier to debug in Debian. Try starting StackApplet by running `'python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py'`. Please post any output you receive.

Comment: As requested see OP.

Comment: @ptr: It seems like the port that StackApplet uses is already in use (StackApplet uses port 8140 for managing preferences). Can you check if StackApplet is already running? When it is working properly, you should see an icon in your notification area (the panel at the top of your desktop).

Comment: I can't see anything in the notification area, especially not the stackapp icon.  Other active programs in the notification area include Thunderbird and Compiz Fusion.  Do you perceive any conflict here?

Comment: In case this tells you anything, peter@debian-peter:~$ lsof -i :8140
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python  6987 peter    7u  IPv4  52025      0t0  TCP localhost:8140 (LISTEN)

Comment: @ptr: It must be running somewhere. Since it sounds like the web interface is running, you can simply open your browser and visit `'http://localhost:8140'`. That will bring up the preferences page which will allow you to configure the application.

Comment: I tried visiting http://localhost:8140/ and whilst I could see a heading "StackApplet Preferences", all that appears on the page are empty bullet points, an empty dropdown menu, radio buttons and check boxes with no accompanying text.  Can you suggest anything else?  I'm happy to provide any info you think might be helpful and diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @ptr: If everything is empty, that means that the translation subsystem is not functioning properly. Is there any way you could make sure that there are no running instances of StackApplet and then try running it from the terminal again? It sounds like it is still running somehow. If you can get it running in a terminal, then we'll hopefully see some error messages that will make it easier to pinpoint what exactly the problem is.

Comment: What commands shall I use to launch it in terminal?

Comment: @ptr: `'python /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py'`

Comment: Ok, so it's giving the same error: address already in use.  How do I vacate the address?  What command?

Comment: @ptr: It should be as simple as `'kill xxx'` where `xxx` is the ID of the process. To find the ID of the StackApplet process, you will need to use Debian's system monitor tool (I'm not sure if that's what it's called, but basically it's the tool that lists all of the currently running programs - StackApplet will probably show up somewhere under Python). Once you find the process ID and `'kill'` StackApplet, then you should have no problem running StackApplet from the terminal.

Comment: In System Monitor I found the process "python usr/bin/system-config-printer-applet" - this was the only python process running.  When I stopped this process and launched StackApplet, it worked.  It appeared some vital printing applet was occupying the port/address.  Can you make StackApplet use a different, vacant port?

Comment: @ptr: I haven't released v1.5 yet, so yes - I can and will change the port number. Thanks for helping me with this - I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, thanks for programming StackApplet. :)  Do you think the problem is the same with Windows XP?  I had a similar issue with launching StackApplet in Windows...

Comment: @ptr: It could be. I'll let you know when I make the next release with the modified port so that you can try it.

Comment: Sounds good.  Though, if you want me to try anything in the meantime, just let me know.  I'll try vacating the port and seeing if it makes a difference...

Comment: In WinXP there is no process taking up port 8140.  Can I launch StackApplet from within terminal to see errors?  If so, what command do I use?  Basically launching it via the start menu, nothing appears to happen...

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd mention.  I tried setting up StackApps in Windows 7, but at the preference screen for accounts associated with StackApps, it stalls on "loading..." and I'm not able to set up my accounts.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome? If so, you can right-click on the page and click "Inspect Element". There will be a console tab somewhere that may contain error information.

Comment: No, Firefox 3.6.12.

Comment: @ptr: In that case, you would go to Tools->Error Console.

Comment: Error: Translator.translation_table is null
Source File: http://localhost:8140/translations.js
Line: 56

Comment: @ptr: Are you using the 1.5beta2 Windows installer?

Comment: stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe was what I used...I guess this is not it?

Comment: @ptr: Well (and this is my fault) I actually didn't change the filenames for the different beta releases, so it's hard to tell which one you have by the filename. However, if you visit [this](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet/+download) page, you can make sure you have beta2. (Oh, and the version in the PPA now uses port 8150).

Comment: I don't know how to explain this but after uninstalling and reinstalling yet again, it worked!  Well this saves you the headache.  Let me suggest an unrelated improvement though.  On relaunching a second instance of StackApplet, a second instance will display on the notification tray.  Not sure if this behaviour is desirable as redundant instances can occur.

Comment: @ptr: Good point. I'll make sure that gets fixed. Thanks for letting me know that it works!

Comment: No problems, happy to help.  We've succeeded in getting it to work for both Debian 6.0 and Windows 7 now, at least for me.  The last remaining OS environment to troubleshoot was going to be WinXP, however, my ailing HHD finally gave in yesterday so I won't have the WinXP environment to test it in. Haven't tried it in Ubuntu yet, but I'll be sure to let you know if I have any issues.  I'm a multi-booting power user, so I appreciate the cross-platform support. :)

Comment: @ptr: Great! Actually, I develop the application in Ubuntu, so it is *extremely* well supported there and has some extra features.

Comment: Oh, I use Debian as my primary OS, as well as Windows.  :P  I hope soon you will extend all those nice features to the other OSs too. :)

Comment: @ptr: Well, the only thing missing from Debian / Windows is integration with the Ubuntu Messaging Menu. All of the other features are present in other operating systems.

Comment: @ptr: I may have a fix for the XP problem now. Please try downloading [this](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe) installer and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Slight problem...I've converted to Win7 now :| But I'm sure some XP user somewhere will be thanking you. Perhaps you could find/get someone with XP to test it for us :P I'd still be curious to know if the problem's been solved :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get with the debug version under Windows XP SP3:

```
C:\Program Files\StackApplet>stackapplet.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 88, in <module>
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 436, in importHook
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 521, in doimport
  File "Z:\tmp\a\other\windows\build\pyi.win32\stackapplet\outPYZ1.pyz/gtk", line 40, in <module>
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 477, in importHook
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 495, in doimport
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 297, in getmod
  File "C:\PyInstaller\archive.py", line 468, in getmod
  File "C:\PyInstaller\iu.py", line 109, in getmod
ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.
```

Comment: @GeorgeEdison ...pssst, over here!

Comment: As mentioned above, please try [this](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe) file and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi @george, I tried 1.5beta2 today and still no go. I'm trying your fix now.

Comment: Installed the fix, and nothing. I'm having the same problem as ptrcao below, @george

Comment: I just made another build. Does [this](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/temp/stackapplet_1.5_i686_setup.exe) file work?

Comment: @George yeah, that works! Only thing is that I get "Network error." on everything since I'm behind a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

So I used `apt-get install stackapplet`, and it installed something. (Version 1.4.0-1, from the `apt-cache show` output.)

Then nothing happens. Should the applet automatically appear somewhere, or do I have to start it manually? If so, how?

(I have Ubuntu 11.04, with an old GNOME desktop, as my computer is too old to support Unity.)

Comment: You can start it manually by going to Applications->Accessories->StackApplet. After that, you can go to preferences and set it to start every time you log in.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you George. It works for me (ubuntu 11) after installing via command prompt. Maybe it could be made also to start from the command prompt with the command stackapplet?

`$ sudo apt-get install stackapplet
Läser paketlistor... Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd

Läser tillståndsinformation... Färdig
Följande ytterligare paket kommer att installeras:
  python-gnomeapplet
Följande NYA paket kommer att installeras:
  python-gnomeapplet
Följande paket kommer att uppgraderas:
  stackapplet
1 att uppgradera, 1 att nyinstallera, 0 att ta bort och 224 att inte uppgradera.
Behöver hämta 52,6 kB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer 79,0 MB att frigöras på disken.
Vill du fortsätta [J/n]? J
Läs:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main python-gnomeapplet amd64 2.32.0-0ubuntu2 [19,8 kB]
Läs:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/universe stackapplet all 1.4.0-1 [32,9 kB]
Hämtade 52,6 kB på 0s (107 kB/s)

Väljer tidigare ej valt paket python-gnomeapplet.
(Läser databasen ... 147381 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Packar upp python-gnomeapplet (från .../python-gnomeapplet_2.32.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Förbereder att ersätta stackapplet 1.4.0 (med .../stackapplet_1.4.0-1_all.deb) ...
Packar upp ersättande stackapplet ...
Hanterar utlösare för bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Hanterar utlösare för desktop-file-utils ...
Hanterar utlösare för python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.sv_SE.utf8.cache...
Hanterar utlösare för python-support ...
Ställer in python-gnomeapplet (2.32.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Ställer in stackapplet (1.4.0-1) ...
Hanterar utlösare för python-support ...
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/Lexar/$ stackapplet
stackapplet: command not found`

Comment: It's not working for me. When I try and connect to `http://localhost:8150/` the drop down menu for the site is empty and so is the search for user section. When starting the applet from the command line it says: `dbind-WARNING **: 08:33:42.461: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply.` and it also says that when I launch preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to get notifications about badges too?

Thank you for a great app!

Comment: You're welcome! Badge notification is planned for a future release.

Comment: @NathanOsman did I miss it or is there still no os x version :(

Comment: There's no OS X *release* but if you have Python and PyGTK installed, there's no reason you couldn't just run it directly from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a GUI toolkit (pygtk? haven't looked at the source), it doesn't make much sense to have your preferences as local website; if anything, it's a security risk.

Any chance that the Preferences feature will be rewritten with a proper GUI?

Comment: The small HTTP server that manages the preferences is quite secure - it uses a cryptographic nonce to ensure that only the current user can make changes to it. But yes, I am planning to rewrite the application in Qt and this will include a brand new dialog box for preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work behind a proxy server?

I am trying to add my AskUbuntu Account, but the Preferences dialog just freezes after some time.

StackApplet Version is 1.4.0-2

Comment: I would strongly suggest upgrading to 1.5.1 which is the latest stable release. A lot of bugs were fixed in that release.

Answer (score 0):

#### Feature Request

Please add support for proxies... It would be helpful to people behind proxies. Like myself.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the icon, it brings up the window. If you click on the icon while the window is open, it pops up again, instead of closing. Just a small feature request.

Also, it would be nice if when you clicked on one of the notifications in the window, if it would get rid of the notification on the SE website. And vice versa

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Not sure if this is a bug on my end, but recently the application has been giving me network errors for Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, and Raspberry Pi SE. I attempted reinstalling both via DEB and via the PPA, but it still was giving me errors.</strike>

So, I tried removing all of them, and then tried to add them back, but I get this:

[image]

and there are no options under Site. Is this a bug somehow, or a result of an API change or the update?

**EDIT**: It's now just giving me **Unknown error**:

[image: unknown error]

Any idea what could be causing this?

**EDIT**: Found the cause. There is an issue with the 1.5.1 version, 1.5.2 is working *almost* perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I select the **Preferences** menu item on Ubuntu 14.04:

> Invalid authorization credentials supplied. Please click on the
>   preferences menu item in the application to view this page.

I reinstalled 1.5.2 and I have been getting this. All of the provided accounts from the previous installation are showing the correct rep, but I can't add new accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the application normal behavior, but I'm only able to see my reputation on a lot of SE sites, while I don't receive any notification at all (such as when someone comments/replies to a question of mine). Is this normal?
I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and I'm using the 1.5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

## Stuck at "add a new account" with v.1.5.2, Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit

After a long break (due to unsolved problems) I tried using this applet again today following the up-to-date installation procedures (basically using the latest PPA and remembering to check   that python-appindicator is installed) but unfortunately this time I couldn't even start logging into my account no matter what I did -- entering my user name or my email address or using "Find User", etc.

I started the applet from terminal to see any error messages, but nothing was there to see either.

Answer (score 0):

**[Unable to install on Kubuntu 23.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/stackapplet/+bug/2034576)** *(PPA Bug-report)*

---

1. I downloaded the latest version, which is as of this writing, v1.5.2.
2. I then right-clicked the deb file to opn with `QApt Package Installer" which is the default app.
3. In the window that pops-up i see a red line saying "Error: Cannot satisfy dependencies".

This is most likely due to `python2.7` usage which has been replaced with `Python 3.11.4`.
My system is fully updated.

[image]

---

PS: Is this app still worked on or is it "abandon ware"?