# StackStalker: Be Notified When Your Question Is Updated (Chrome Extension)

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

[image: StackStalker screen shot]

## StackStalker

**Monitor any question from any Stack Exchange site and see when it is updated.**

Latest version: 3.0.2 | Updated: May 5, 2017

- Minor bug fix to work on `https` sites.

Rewritten from near-scratch to use v2.2 of the Stack Exchange API, **StackStalker** is a **chrome extension** that will monitor any question on any [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites) site and let you know when something has updated. Don't sit there and mash your F5 key waiting for something to happen. Instead, while viewing a question, click the StackStalker icon next to the address bar, and click the "Add this question" button. Then go browse something else while StalkStalker does the work for you. No need for logging in or creating a Stack Exchange account.

When you've added one or more questions, the logo will turn from gray (inactive) to blue (active). When a question has been updated, meaning the answer count, comment count, upvote count, or answer acceptance status has been updated, the icon will display a number for how many questions have been updated.

Clicking on the StackStalker icon will bring up a popup window displaying the questions you've chosen to monitor. On the left of each question are at least two action buttons: toggle monitor (eye icon) and delete (X icon). If the question has been updated, its background will turn yellow and you'll have one more action button: mark as read (book icon).

If you click on the eye icon, it will open or close the eye, indicating whether or not StackStalker will actively check for updates to this question. It's recommended that you un-monitor older, less active questions to prevent unnecessary requests to the Stack Exchange API.

Clicking the X icon will remove the question from your list. You can always add it back by revisiting the question and adding it again.

Clicking the book icon will remove the "updated" status from the question you are monitoring without navigating to the question. If you click the title of the question, it will remove the "updated" status as well.

Please feel free to direct suggestions, bugs, or pull requests to the [StackStalker repository](https://github.com/ultimatedelman/stackstalker).

#### License

Free! Get it **[here](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo)**

#### Download

Get it **[here](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/paoeolblihedcagbofkkkecjilmpehmo)** from the Google Chrome Web Store.

#### Platform

This extension is for Google Chrome only.

### Contact

Created by me, Jason Edelman. If you want to contact me, my info is on the website listed in my profile, or you can just leave a comment here (I'll be monitoring this thread :)

### Code

This was written entirely in HTML5, CSS3, and Javascript + jQuery. The code is open-source in [this repo](https://github.com/ultimatedelman/stackstalker). Pull requests and bug reports/fixes welcome!

Comment: If you made me a version for Super User, you'd have an instant user

Comment: Please don't use URL shortening services. They are completely unnecessary. This is not Twitter.

Comment: @dennis - ha, sorry, i was posting it around and just had that on my clipboard

Comment: @ivo i will try to make it cross-SE compatible. that's always been the idea, i just don't know how without hard-coding each site: http://stackapps.com/questions/499/what-is-the-best-way-to-provide-support-for-an-unknowable-number-of-stackexchange

Comment: Jason, please follow the [app] announcement template.  http://stackapps.com/questions/7/how-to-list-your-application-on-stack-apps

Comment: @ivo - (and everyone else) i have updated it now to run all stack exchange sites :) i haven't had time to update the documentation yet, but i'm getting there!

Comment: @kevin documentation updated!

Comment: Awesome @Jason! Going to try it out again RIGHT NOW

Comment: @ivo let me know what you think! it's still in development so there may be some bugs, but i think in general it does the job :)

Comment: @kevin thanks :) see how quickly i was able to respond? wonder why? :D

Comment: @Jason: it does his job well, though I'd love to have it note me on moderator flags and stuff as well... But those aren't include in the API are they?

Comment: Oh and I'm using it now to keep track of this question too ;-)

Comment: @ivo - unfortunately i don't think the API has any moderator stuff built in, but if it did that would be pretty cool. I'm not a moderator of any site so i wouldn't even be able to test it! haha

Comment: This extension rocks.

Comment: Is it possible to have this use Google Sync so that watched questions sync between computers?

Comment: @daniel i'd like to be able to sync between comps, but i don't think google sync is how to do it: http://www.google.com/sync/index.html it looks like all that service does is sync contacts, calendars, and email

Comment: Please consider listing StackStalker on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: @george - listed! i like the site!

Comment: @Jason: Thanks! I put it together last week after people started complaining that there was no 'app-store' for the apps / libraries here. Any suggestions for features, etc.?

Comment: @george - yeah, make the "search" search the tags as well as the description. i didn't have "chrome extension" in my description but i had both in my tags and my app didn't come up. also, if you showed links to other apps that had the same tags, that would be cool. a tag autocomplete would be nice and reduce tag noise as well. those are just my first impressions. otherwise, very nice! i wish i could follow it using my app, hahaha

Comment: @Jason: I am planning a tag search feature... good idea listing similar apps by tag. As for your last point, maybe I should expose an API :)

Comment: @george ps, are you by chance using my app to follow this thread? or are you just hanging around the site

Comment: @Jason: I'm using [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop) :)

Comment: @george ah, cute. that looks cool too!

Comment: @Jason - I was thinking of whatever service Google uses to sync bookmarks, but some quick searching didn't uncover much information.

Comment: @Jason: Hey, I put together an API for StackList that closely resembles the SO API. You can find details [here](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/api/).

Comment: @george ha! great! if you wanted, you could completely repurpose a lot of my code to make one that follows apps on your site :)

Comment: @Jason: Are you going to add support for StackList to StackStalker? That would be great - then people would be notified when new apps are posted, etc.

Comment: @george hm... dunno... the api is different... it would take a lot of finagling to make it work alongside the stackexchange stuff. plus there are no votes/answers or anything like that

Comment: @Jason: I tried my hardest to make the API as similar as possible. The JSON, the arrays, etc. Any ideas for further changes are welcome.

Comment: @george yeah there are a lot of similarities, but the format is still too different to easily incorporate it (QA site vs just an app listing). i suppose i can put it in as a future development, but i'm not sure when i'll be touching this project again (working for free makes less money than working for money :)

Comment: this extension is AWESOME, could you please add the possibility to track also the question made in the beta stackexchange sites?

Comment: Well to my knowledge it doesn't even work on Gaming.SE

Comment: @Jason can you add shortcut keys? First: To add question instead of having to click the button. Second: Delete or stop following the current questions. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of things I need to do, but that's a pretty good suggestion! :)

Comment: @IvoFlipse now works on all sites!

Comment: @KevinMontrose fyi, freshly updated for v2.2 of API :)

Comment: @Marcx fyi, just updated to use the new API! should work on ALL stack exchange sites!

Comment: @DustyCampbell recently updated to use the new api!