# OBSOLETE - Stack Exchange Notifier Chrome Extension

Tags: app, obsolete, chrome-extensions, notifier, extension

> #Obsolete: Links are dead; no source code.

#### About

Stack Exchange Notifier is a handy extension for Google Chrome browser that displays your current reputation, badges on Stack Exchange sites and notifies you on reputation's changes. You will now get notified of comments on your own posts (questions and answers) and of any comments that refer to you by @username in a comment, even if you do not own the post (aka mentions). 
All Stack Exchange sites are supported.

#### Screenshots

[![][1]][3]

[![][4]][4]

[![][5]][5]

[image]
[image]
[![][6]][6]

#### Access

[Install extensions from Google Chrome Extension Gallery][2]

#### Platform

Google Chrome browser extension

#### Contact

Created by me (Vladislav Tserman). I'm available at: vladjan (at) gmail.com  
*Follow Stack Exchange Notifier on twitter to get notified about news and updates:* http://twitter.com/se_notifier

#### Code

Written in Java, Google Web Toolkit under Eclipse Helios.   
Stack Exchange Notifier uses the Stack Exchange API and is powered by Google App Engine for Java.

#### Changelog

**I will be porting extension to not use app engine back-end due to some limitations.  New versions of the extension will be making direct calls to Stack Exchange API right from your browser. Please do not expect new versions of the extension any time soon. Sorry.  
Read more about limitations here https://stackapps.com/questions/1713 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949815**

***Currently, you may sometimes experience some issues using extension, but most users will have no problems. You may notice too many errors in the logs, but there is nothing I can do with this now.  Thanks for using my little app,  thanks to all of you it still works in spite of many issues with API***

**Version 1.2.9.3** - Thursday, October 14, 2010

- Bug fix release (back-end improvements)

**Version 1.2.9.2** - Thursday, October 07, 2010

- Bug fix release (high rate of occasional API errors were noticed so some fixes added to handle them were possible)

**Version 1.2.9.1** - Tuesday, October 05, 2010

- Mostly bug fix release, back-end performance improvements
- You will now get notified of comments on your own posts (questions and answers) that are not older than 1 year and of any comments that refer to you by @username in a comment, even if you do not own the post (aka mentions). This is experimental feature, let me know if you like/need it.
- New 'All sites' view displays all websites from Stack Exchange network (part of new feature that is not finished yet)

**Version 1.2.9** - Saturday, September 25, 2010

- Fixes an issue when some users got empty Account view.
- When hovering on @Username on account view the title now displays '@Username on @SiteName' to easily understand the site name

**Version 1.2.7** - Wednesday, September 22, 2010

- Fixed an issue with notifications.
- Minor improvements

**Version 1.2.5** - Tuesday, September 21, 2010

- Fixed an issue where some characters in response payload raised an exception when parsing to JSON.

**v1.2.3** (Sunday, September 19, 2010)

- Support for new OpenID providers was added (Yahoo, MyOpenID, AOL)
- UI improvements
- Several minor defects were fixed

**v1.2.2** (Thursday, September 16, 2010)

- New types of notifications added. Now extension notifies you on comments that are directed to you. Comments are expandable, so clicking on comment title will expand height to accommodate all available text.
- UI and error handling improvements

#### Future

Application still in beta stage. I hope you're not having any problems, but if you are, please let me know. Leave your feedback and bug reports in comments. I'm available at: vladjan (at) gmail.com.

I'm working on adding new features.
I want to hear from the users and incorporate as much feedback as possible into the extension.
**Any suggestions for improvements/features to add?**

Comment: Why does it require a Google login?

Comment: @Dennis, This extension requests your reputations, badges, etc not directly from stack exchange api endpoints, but using its backend to request data in batch. It tracks associations between you and your stack exchange accounts in datastore and uses OpenID to confirms your identity. Now it supports only Google, but I will add other OpenID providers soon.
Let me know if you feel that something is not right with this approach. At least it allows you to run extension on any number of computers.

Comment: So why do I have to login with openID at all? Cant I just enter my profile number. I downloaded it about 5 minutes before posting

Comment: I thought I already answered this question before, but ok, probably you are right and this should be optional for those people who want synchronize settings between different browsers/computers.
Did you managed to add your accounts?

Comment: I upgraded Chrome on the machine that it was working on, and indeed it no longer works. So probably not the extension's fault (unless it was relying on previously buggy behavior, but that's unlikely)

Comment: I'm glad to report that the latest Chrome dev build (10.0.648.82) the extension works perfectly once again!

Comment: @Adrian Came here to say the very same thing!

Comment: I'm very sad to see this app go unmaintained :(.

Comment: Is there any alternative ?

Comment: @SmartManoj, see [this search](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/notifier%2b-obsolete?tab=Active).

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to SEApps, and given the design of it, I apologize if bug reports are not supposed to be "Answers". Please let me know and I'll move it to the OP comments.

That having been said, I just installed this extension, and have a problem. Why can't I manually specify an OpenID in the extension configuration? I don't use a common vendor, I have my own.

Comment: You are not alone with such problem. I've already answered question from user on following page http://goo.gl/yDa9. In future versions I will eliminate need of OpenId login (It will be required just to synchronize extension settings between computers)

Comment: Unfortunately, this extension is useless without the ability to specify an OpenID provider.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better to change the title of the "username" from "username" to "site name" in the "Accounts" page. It will help peoples to understand the site name easily.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for feedback. It will be ready by the end of the week in Version 1.2.9. The title will show something like '@Username on StackOverflow'.

Comment: Version 1.2.9 released!

Comment: @Vladislav Tserman: Another feature to include in the next version 1.3 (not mentioned in this<https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/onbgjnpdcjdhjngbnhnhplnamagmiike> page): play notification sound.

Comment: @Vladislav Tserman: And another feature to include is "Remember me" checkbox in the login page.

Comment: Icons not working on os 10.8.3, Chrome (latest)

Answer (score 4):

This is a very slick, awesome-looking extension with lots of potential.

My main feature request would be for the ability to be notified of changes to *any* question (not just your own), the way that [StackStalker](https://stackapps.com/questions/493/stackstalker-be-notified-when-your-question-is-updated-chrome-extension) does it. This would be great since it looks like StackStalker's author has lost interest in it and hasn't added support for arbitrary Stack Exchange sites yet.

Keep up the great work!

Comment: thanks for your feedback, glad that you like it. 
Configurable notifications of new questions and of changes to any question you like on Stack Exchange network sites is first in my todo list for next major update.

Comment: That's really great to hear :) I'm looking forward to my Stack Exchange Notifier notification of updates to this question, then ;)

Comment: i haven't lost interest, i just haven't had the time! haha... i definitely want to support all SE sites :)

Answer (score 3):

Two problems that I have:

1. My display username is "Nomæd" with a unicode letter æ, but it appears as �� instead.
2. I have 6 associated accounts, and the main one is http://atheism.stackexchange.com/ but I can't make it appear in my list of accounts in any way.

Anyone has solutions, mainly for problem no. 2?

Comment: I've just finished 2-month contract project and ready to address accumulated issues with extension.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, needz moar escaping: My notifications for the question [Implement <!— language: lang-css --> in preview](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/89592/implement-language-lang-css-in-preview) are showing as "Implement in preview"!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to log-in but Google says that there is a new OpenId standard as:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6206245?p=openid&rd=1#survey=true

[image]

Please fix!

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this app is way obsolete and no longer supported.  You'll probably have to fork the source and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I know you just posted this:

> I will be porting extension to not use app engine back-end due to some limitations. New versions of the extension will be making direct calls to Stack Exchange API right from your browser. Please do not expect new versions of the extension any time soon. Sorry.
>
> Currently, you may experience some issues using extension, but most users will have no problems. You may notice too many errors in the logs, but there is nothing I can do with this now. Thanks for using my little app.

but I thought I would let you know that I am having to re-authenticate every time I log in (and sometimes when I've already been logged in for a while). I use OpenID, and after telling OpenID to remember me, it's just a matter of clicking on your icon, clicking the OpenID button, and then waiting for the page that says "Yaay, we're logged in!"

Otherwise, I absolutely love it! It looks nice and works well. I especially like that comments have part of the text (and all of it on hover). Thanks for all your hard work!

Comment: glad that you like the extension. In future versions I will completely eliminate need of OpenID for login (It will be required just in order to synchronize extension settings between computers).

Answer (score 2):

The escaping issue has [been mentioned](https://stackapps.com/a/2381/9371) already, but I'd just like to accentuate it with a screenshot -

> [image]

As you can see, the HTML is actually being rendered. In the case of an HTML comment, the content is simply not displayed, but HTML content here is being showed as an un-ordered list item.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108749/blur-entire-li-except-last-word) is a link to the post from the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

## Doesn't work in Linux.

Yep, just as the title says, this extension is absolutely, 100% non-functioning on Linux.

After installing, I clicked on its icon, signed in, and saw this success message:

> #### Congratulations, you've been successfully authenticated. Enjoy Stack Exchange Notifier!
>
> ## Stack Exchange Notifier authorized!

...but the icon still has the red question mark on it.
Attempting to re-authorize just opens an empty tab.

If I restart the browser, I can (try to) sign in again, and am greeted with the same "success" message, but get the same results as before.

Answer (score 2):

For the first time in my life I used Facebook integration to login to stackoverflow, and what a surprise, I can't use it because I don't see how to configure it with it.

I had to uninstall.