# Is there an app to monitor reputation and new answers/comments?

Tags: discussion, app-request, reputation-audit

Is there a desktop app that will alert me when my reputation changes, and when I have a new answer or comment on any of my questions?

Answer (score 2):

There sure is: [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-stackoverflow-meets-the-gnome-desktop).

Keep in mind that right now, it is only available for Linux users - but a Windows version is in the works.

Answer (score 1):

I ve heard the guys at busyfounder.com are preparing an app called busydeveloper that will add github, hackernews and stackoverflow in order to track this kind of data.