# SENotifier, a Stack Exchange inbox notifier for Mac OS X

Tags: app, inbox, mac-os-x, notifier, systemtray

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### Updates

#### Version 1.1

- Added support for Notification Center (10.8 and later)
- Adjusted menu icon to align better with existing menu items
- Auto-update is now supported via [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/)

#### Version 1.0

- Option to automatically start at login
- Login token now requested with `no_expiry` (you may need to re-allow after upgrading)
- New application icon

#### Version 0.5

- Now compatible with Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and later
- Different hide times are now available
- Status icon is black when there are no messages (thanks Kevin Sołtysiak)
- Better error handling and reporting on inbox checking failure

#### Version 0.4

- [Growl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growl_%28software%29) support built-in (optional, notifications off by default)
- Site icon is now displayed in notification menu items

### About

SENotifier is a Mac OS X app that shows the current contents of your Stack Exchange inbox in the menu bar and was inspired by [Gmail Notifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail_interface#Applications).

I created this app so the inbox notifier would be visible all the time, instead of only when a Stack Exchange page was loaded in the browser.

This app uses the new Stack Exchange API v2.0 with authentication, so it can get the current contents of your inbox.

#### License

BSD license.

#### Download

[Download](http://hewgill.com/senotifier/stack-exchange-notifier-1.1.dmg) (750 KB `.dmg`)

Or install with Homebrew:

```
brew cask install stack-exchange-notifier
```

#### Platform

SENotifier requires Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) or later.

### Contact

[Greg Hewgill](http://hewgill.com)

### Code

This app is developed in Objective-C using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 4.2. No (Stack Exchange) libraries were harmed in the creation of this software (that means the authentication flow is all straight Objective-C code). [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) is used for the JSON parsing bits.

The code is available on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) at https://github.com/ghewgill/senotifier.

### Self-promotion

[image]

Comment: @GregHewgill It would be nice to have an option to **check for update**.

Comment: Download link isn't working for me.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: Failing power supply in server has been replaced. Download link should be working again!

Comment: @GregHewgill I've encountered a problem with the Stack Exchange Notifier App and want to mention it here:

**My Macbook Pro will not sleep automatically when the Notifier is running**. It took me quite some time of trial and error  to isolate the problem to the Notifier.

Comment: @gentmatt: That's very strange, I don't even know *how* to prevent a machine from sleeping. Also, my machine sleeps just fine even with the notifier running. Question for you: Does this problem still happen when you choose the "Hide for xx hours" option in the notifier?

Comment: Very nice - I love the menu icon's states.

Comment: @GregHewgill When I use the "hide" option, the mac sleeps reliably. When the notifier is running, it probably never sleeps. Why do I say probably now? Well, this morning was the *first* time (out of a dozen) where I've left my computer running with the SE notifier open and it managed to sleep. But it must have happened a lot later than configured in the Energy Saver settings.

Comment: @gentmatt: It sounds like regular network activity may be causing your machine not to sleep. If you use Gmail, I wonder if you could try the [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html) to see whether it causes the same kind of problem.

Comment: @gentmatt: I thought I had reproduced the no-sleep problem, but after controlled testing (and closing a bunch of other stuff), my Macbook (Air, Lion) sleeps consistently whether or not the notifier is running.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yeah, I'm also confused as to what is causing the problem. I can't really relate it to the SE notifier 100% anymore. At the moment I just have to live with my MBP's insomnia. :(

Comment: An auto updater would be awesome... :)

Comment: Will there be a update where it check stackoverflow page as well ? Would be awesome.

Comment: @YvesR: Sorry, could you clarify that? Which stackoverflow page are you referring to?

Comment: @GregHewgill Sorry, ignore my comment. I was just thinking the posts only rely to stack exchange itself, not on all platforms. Clarified my confusion now.

Comment: I found a minor bug. Whenever I get a new comment I get the Growl message twice.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: Is it possible that you have two instances of the notifier running at the same time? This can happen accidentally if you ask it to hide itself, then start another one.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.. but I'll have a look.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. It seems I only have one running.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: Do you have the Growl application installed? If so, which version?

Comment: Have 1.3.3 installed. And yes, the old (non-appstore) version is uninstalled. I only have one growl instance running.

Comment: Growl's log shows two notifications from "Stack Exchange Notifier", one with and one without icon. Checked my `ps -A |grep Stack` again, and have only one instance running.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: That's curious. Thanks for the info, I'll see if I can find out why that is happening.

Comment: Ok. let me know if I can help out with anything else.

Comment: How can I make the app forget my login settings?

Comment: @Owen: Use "Invalidate login token".

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yes, but then when I click login, it just automatically auths and doesnt give me the opportunity to correct my log in details.

Comment: @Owen: That's your browser (Safari) interacting with the web site to log you in automatically (out of the control of the notifier). So to do a full re-login, you also have to log out of the web site too (delete associated cookies if all else fails).

Comment: @GregHewgill: Ah ok, wasn't sure what browser it was firing (I never use safari, Opera all the way!)

Comment: Is there any way to tell it to remove a comment from the notification? If I've already seen enough of it in the StackExchange inbox pop-up, and decided not to bother going to the page, I don't need it in the menu as well.

Comment: @Barmar: If you clear your SE inbox on the web site, then the messages should also disappear from the notifier. Note that there is a [current bug](http://stackapps.com/questions/3730/unread-messages-in-inbox-query-shows-older-inbox-messages) that sometimes causes old messages to temporarily reappear in the notifier.

Comment: Any chance of http://github.com/ghewgill/senotifier/pull/7 being implemented?

Comment: Can it do the opposite of what I asked earlier: when you go from the notifier to SO, can it mark that notification as read in your SE inbox?

Comment: @Barmar: No, the SE API does not provide any way for a program such as the notifier to mark individual items as "read".

Comment: this tool would be so nice for older mac's `:(..` since our iphone generation has new ones every year, they all forgett about compatibility on os x in general. i need a psychologist now, or someone recognizes the used frameworks here are existing in older mac's too and codes a bit memory management in it.. :/!

Comment: Does anybody know if there's anything like this for Gnome? I've used this particular one in Mac, and it's great, but I'm switching to Debian now, and I'd like a similar thing.

Comment: Any chance for some Retina display icons for the menu bar? @GregHewgill

Comment: This is awesome!  Could we be notified of reputation changes please?

Comment: @GregHewgill It'd be great if there was some sort of notification that you were actually logged in from the dropdown; possibly changing the 'log in' option to whatever username you were logged in under, something along those lines?

Comment: I'm seeing "JSON parse error" today. Is there an issue with this?

Comment: @Barmar: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235000/byte-order-mark-appearing-at-the-beginning-of-api-calls for the status of this current Stack Exchange API bug.

Comment: This is a fantastic app. Maybe add an option to clear all the notifications? When I get more than one notification (often on the same question) it's annoying to have to click each one individually even though it goes to the same question.

Comment: @Jason: To clear all notifications, go to SE itself (the web site), and click on the red notification counter icon in the top bar. After a few minutes, the notifier will clear all its notifications when it next updates.

Comment: @AlexanderMacLeod I have done it.

Comment: I can't download it. Anyone can send it to me? Thanks

Comment: I download it. And then what? It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 14):

Very good. I've been looking for something simple like this for a while. Thanks. As potential future features;

- <s>Growl integration would be great</s>
- <s>An option to temporarily disable notifications (i.e. when you want to get some work done and don't want to get distracted by revisiting your answers etc!)</s>
- <s>A 'run on startup' option</s>
- <s>Maybe have the default menubar icon as black and when you receive a notification change it to the current blue icon along with the count. Similar to how [Sparrow](http://www.sparrowmailapp.com/) works:</s>
- <s>Notification Center Support!</s>

  [image]

  [image]

  so something like:

  [image]

Comment: I've just uploaded a new version with a "hide" option. I'll have to look into Growl support.

Comment: I have to say that's fairly shocking. I added Growl support to try it out and the `.dmg` size went from 80 kb to over 850 kb. Is that expected? Is that considered *reasonable*?

Comment: That sounds unusual. I've never developed with Growl so I'm not sure if that's normal. Maybe there are parts of the framework you can ommit? I added another 2 suggestions for the app. thanks again

Comment: You're right, I had copied too much stuff in there. It's now a somewhat more reasonable 350 kb. New version coming soon!

Comment: I updated my answer to strike off all the new features. I added a request for Notification Center (Mountain Lion) support. If I haved have some time, I can try implement this (although I have no experience with OSX dev)

Comment: I added support for Notification Center in a separate pull request. See screenshot in the answers here below.

Comment: Version 1.1 now supports Notification Center.

Answer (score 8):

I like the current logos of SENotifier, but, I was bored, and decided to have a go at making some SENotifier logos as well.  And, well, here they are!  Tell me if you like them, or any comments!  I don't know if the pictures will keep their formatting, though.  Oh well.

1).

[image: SENotifier Logo (.png)]

(.png)

2.)

[image: SENotifier Logo (.icns)]

(.icns)

Comment: One of these icons should be used for the logo of SE Notifier. They both look nicer than the current one. :)

Answer (score 7):

Any way of porting this to iOS?

Comment: The [Stack Exchange iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8) is available.

Answer (score 5):

I added support for OSX Notification Center and made a pull request.

[image: Example]

Comment: This is cool! Is there a way I can get this version of SENotifier?

Comment: thnx. Yeah, clone my pull-request from github. I do need to fick the click action though... found that out today.

Comment: @Nathan: Version 1.1 (downloadable as .dmg) now has Notification Center support.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Awesome! Thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: Very nice idea here.

Answer (score 4):

I really like this too. It is great! I second @pastylegs' comment. Growl notifications would be very nice.
I also wanted to add another comment. If you look at the SE inbox on the actual website, you'll notice that it displays past, read notifications:

[image: SE inbox]

It would be nice to have several (maybe 5 or so) read notification in the menu bar. I find myself going back to the inbox several times to go to older notifications.

All in all, it's a great little tool and I encourage you to keep up the work!

Comment: Thanks! Notice that if you *don't* click on the inbox icon on the web site, then the read items won't be removed from SENotifier's list.

Comment: @GregHewgill Oh, I didn't notice that. Will try it!

Answer (score 4):

Er… I’m sorry, but I don’t speak robot.  I know enough about computers to get by, more than most civilians, but I was wondering if you could dumb the answer to my problem **a lot** for me please?

The SENotifier for OX was working perfectly until today, when I took my computer away from my house, and wifi.  I’m not sure if disconnecting from the internet had anything to do with it, but the problem started right then.

When I got home I tried to login to the app again and it wouldn’t let me.  When I tried this flashed on the screen for one second:

[image]

then nothing.  It didn’t sign in.  When I toggled over the icon, this is what I saw:

[image]

When I clicked on **“login”** the same **“Authorizing Application”** window would pop up every time, then it still wouldn’t log me in.  I tried everything I could think of.

1. I tried **”Check Now”** a lot of times
2. I clicked **”Check for updates”** several times (to no avail; it would just tell me I had the latest version installed.
3. I **”Quit”** then **”Ejected"** SENotifier, then restarted the whole process again.  Nothing.
4. I **”Deleted"** SENotifier from my Mac, **”ReInstalled"** it, then tried everything again.  Nothing.
5. I tried the beta version, which supposedly didn’t have ***“the bug”*** that they said was causing the problem.  That didn’t help either.

So…give it to me straight.  Am I SOL, or can you help me?  If you have any idea what if wrong, please talk to me like you would a child because even though I am really good with computers, this part is difficult.

Comment: If you're having a problem logging in, try the "Invalidate login token" option. Sometimes the app and the site get out of sync and that option usually fixes it.

Answer (score 3):

Bug report here.
It's not working on CoreDuo MBP/10.6.8

[image]

I suppose because it's 64-bit only but you didn't mention system requirements anywhere here.

Comment: this 64bit problem is not so hard i think, but missing memory management because of Automatic Reference Counting with xcode 4.2 makes it near inpossible to port downward to older mac's :(, if someone knows a nice workaround framework or so.. i would just try to implement it so

Answer (score 3):

I've been recently running into a problem with `SENotifier` where it updates when a message is directed at me, but it always shows an old message rather than the lastest message.

Comment: You know, I've actually noticed the same thing. I haven't narrowed down the problem, but it looks like it might be a problem with the site itself. I'm currently investigating.

Comment: along a similar vein, I also see messages that I've already read coming up as new messages needing to be read.  Only been one or two before now, but logged in today and there were 32.

Answer (score 2):

I have forked your source code, and enabled Retina display support. I have also recreated all the icons.
[Check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/josephyoon/senotifier).

Answer (score 1):

This is an awesome app, great job.

But I think you forgot to make the extra text after "Check Now" change white when you hover over it, see:

[image]

I'm not a Mac App Developer (not yet, anyway) so I don't know if it is possible to change that but I just wanted to let you know about that.

Comment: Thanks! The red message is a warning message, so it probably doesn't matter much. But I'll see if I can find a way to change that.

Comment: @GregHewgill You're welcome! It also does that for the "checked x minutes ago" text.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.3 Update

I have updated all the icons to make it look much better.
You can check out the source code and download the DMG here: https://github.com/josephyoon/senotifier

Answer (score 1):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I'd like to request that the app detects when night mode is enabled under general system preferences and switches the icon to a white color.

This is what the icon currently looks like:

[image: ghost icon]

... too dark. :(

I also created [issue #26, on GitHub](https://github.com/ghewgill/senotifier/issues/26), for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this and its nice. It would be great if this app could implement the new notification API in OSX mountain lion.

Comment: I'm sure they will be able to integrate the new notification center soon.

Comment: Version 1.1 now supports Notification Center.

Answer (score 0):

This is really nice, but it would be great if the "Log In" menu item would change text (maybe to Log Out [User Name]—presumably analogous to the current "Invalidate login token") when the app is logged in. Not currently having any unread notifications I could only assume it had logged in successfully by seeing the screenshots you'd posted here.

It would be doubly nice for that item to show your current rep (your highest single SE site rep), but perhaps I'm just really finicky about checking that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

What does NSURLErrorDomain error -999 mean?

I tried logging in manually, but it said it doesn't exist, even though it works when I log in through my browser.

**Update:** I don't know if this will help. (Originally I was going to upload images, but I only have 1 rep, so I'll just describe it in detail).

1. I open up the app and I get a screen similar to the SE log in web page and click on "log in with Stack Exchange"
2. Then the window "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.) pops up. It gives me one option, which is to click "OK".
3. Next the Stack Exchange Notifier window says "Third Party Cookies Appear To Be Disabled", "You can continue and log in manually however." I log in manually.
4. Stack Exchange OpenID window shows up and I log in. Then it says "Not Found", "This page could not be found."

But I'm able to log in through my browser, so I don't know why it says that.

Comment: I hadn't seen this error before, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024748/how-do-i-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-999-in-iphone-3-0-os provided a clue. Try http://hewgill.com/senotifier/stack-exchange-notifier-beta.dmg and see if that helps. Let me know whether this works for you or not. Thanks!

Comment: @GregHewgill Isn't the beta going to have more bugs than the current version though? I checked out the link you posted, but I don't understand it too well as I don't have much of a background in building apps.

Comment: No, the beta version I posted is exactly the same as the latest version with the addition of a single change that attempts to avoid the -999 error. Please let me know if the version I posted avoids the -999 error or not.

Comment: @GregHewgill Well, it avoids the -999 error, but OpenID still won't recognize my profile. It wouldn't have anything to do with my firewall would it? Gmail's notifier doesn't have any issues with it.

Comment: Ok cool. You say you're able to log in through your browser, but which browser? The notifier uses Safari because that's guaranteed to be available to OS X apps. Make sure that you haven't disabled cookies or something in the Safari settings. Google's login process is different from Stack Exchange so they're not really comparable.

Comment: @GregHewgill Yeah, I set it to never block cookies (on Safari) and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Just to be clear, can you log in normally to the site through Safari itself? I'm not sure why it's not working for you. The notifier really just hands off the job of authentication to the popup browser window, and returns when it's reported as successful. Do you have a different computer you can try it on?

Comment: @GregHewgill Seems to work now. It doesn't log me in though when it opens up firefox. It shows the webpage, but I have to log in through my browser still

Comment: Great, that sounds like it's working normally! When opening a page, the notifier hands the URL off to the OS, which then hands it off to your configured default browser (Firefox), which doesn't know anything about the fact that you're already logged in inside the notifier.

Comment: Love the app. Thanks for the hard work.. My requests.. 1. remove the log in - if logged in.. 2. Any way to get SE reputation numbers? an up vote makes my day :) pretty pathetic eh!

Comment: Any way to logout an account? I've mistakenly logged in with an old Facebook Open ID SE account and want to connect with my Google Open ID SE account.. couldn't find an option, nor the prefs location on mac

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have an option, to open the Website stackoverflow without having a notification.. I assume when you have a new notification you click on it and will be directed to the website. But when i dont have a notification, the app is useless.

Also i agree with Kit Grose, that it is weird to see "Log in" as i am already logged in.

Also it would be nice to give a better (self explanatory) name to the "invalidate login token". As i just installed the app, when i click on it, it seems that it does not do anything. One must directly google it to find out what it actually does. At least it would be nice to have a feedback from this action, like you see when you click "check for updates".

Answer (score 0):

Getting a strange issue here, "OAuth request must be over HTTPS":

[image]
[image]

Any thoughts on what's causing it? I've deleted and reinstalled, no luck. (And tried the invalidate token option).

Comment: As a heads up, this seems to be a general API bug, not specific to this app: ["OAuth request must be over HTTPS" when request is over https](http://stackapps.com/q/4385)

Comment: @TimStone nice catch, problem is resolved now thanks to the new deployment.

Comment: @TimStone  I’m lost, because I am having the exact same problem.  But I don’t understand any of these **”fixes”** anyone is talking about on this thread.  I don’t know how to do any of them.

Comment: @LeahMurdoch are you using the latest version?

Comment: @brandonscript Yeah.  I have downloaded it and re-downloaded it a bunch of times.  And when I click **”Check for Updates”** it tells me I have the latest version: **”Stack Exchange Notifier 1.1”**

Comment: TBH it's a really old app. Possible Tim isn't keeping it updated anymore? Guess we'll see when he replies.

Answer (score 0):

Since updating to OS 10.9 I get crashes, apparently whenever a notification arrives:

```
Process:         Stack Exchange Notifier [50227]
Path:            /Applications/Stack Exchange Notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/Stack Exchange Notifier
Identifier:      hewgill.com.Stack-Exchange-Notifier
Version:         1.1 (8)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [179]
Responsible:     Stack Exchange Notifier [50227]

...

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -bytes only defined for abstract class.  Define -[_NSPlaceholderData bytes]!'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
...
Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f59e41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8bbb5e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f59e2cc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fbaf1d1 NSRequestConcreteImplementation + 231
4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8fb43927 -[NSData(NSData) bytes] + 39
5   Growl                               0x000000010004819b +[GrowlGNTPBinaryChunk identifierForBinaryData:] + 52
6   Growl                               0x000000010004b897 +[GrowlNotificationGNTPPacket getHeaders:binaryChunks:notificationID:forNotificationDict:] + 1083
7   Growl                               0x0000000100046968 +[GrowlGNTPOutgoingPacket outgoingPacketOfType:forDict:] + 261
8   Growl                               0x0000000100038f78 -[GrowlGNTPCommunicationAttempt socket:didConnectToHost:port:] + 36
9   Growl                               0x000000010003ec6c __34-[GrowlGCDAsyncSocket didConnect:]_block_invoke_0 + 79
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff84fe11d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff84fde2ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff84fe5f03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f505839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f4c0b14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f4c0275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8fe1df0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 226
17  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8fe1dcb7 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 479
18  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8fe1dabc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 65
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff854c928e _DPSNextEvent + 1434
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff854c88db -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff854bc9cc -[NSApplication run] + 553
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff854a7803 NSApplicationMain + 940
23  Stack Exchange Notifier             0x00000001000018c8 start + 52
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

...
```

Comment: It looks like that crash is happening in the Growl library. For OS X 10.8 and later, you should choose "Enable Notifications (OS X)" from the Preferences menu, and turn off Growl. Growl is only needed for older OS X that doesn't have Notification Center.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Unless one hates (and has disabled) Notification Center and prefers (and uses) Growl instead. What's likely happening here is that I've killed NS and prevented it from launching at all, and SE Notifier is getting stuck on that. Is there any prospect of a revision that survives in that kind of environment?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Is there any prospect of an update that works with [Notification Center disabled](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106149/4395)?

Comment: @GregHewgill: Is there anything I can do to get this working on a system where [NC has been disabled](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/106149/4395)?

Comment: I suppose you could rebuild the SENotifier app with a version of the Growl library that has this bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your current for login is a `Log in` and a `Invalidate login token` (i.e. log out). There is no way for the user to tell if he/she is logged in or not right now. I find that really annoying, and wonder when not getting any messages if I am actually logged in.

What if you just had a `Logout` single `NSMenuItem` when the user is logged in (which is set to `NSState NSOnState`), and with a `Login` item when the user is logged out (which is set to `NSState NSOffState`). This effectively makes a toggle, and seems like better design. :)

Comment: Pull requests accepted. :) https://github.com/ghewgill/senotifier

Comment: Its weird getting that message about SENotifier from SENotifier XD

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be "that guy", but SE notifier is not gatekeeper-compliant. Any chance of getting it code-signed?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get the different hide times to work. No matter what time I select, it only hides for 25 minutes. I'm on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the app, I've used it for about two years now, and it does what it is supposed to.

There is just one minor bug, when I boot up my computer (OS X 10.6.8) and SENotifier automatically launches, I initially get the "This computer's internet connection appears to be offline" alert. If I just click "log in" in the popup menu it works normally. Maybe there is a timing issue, my Wi-Fi connecting hardware is perhaps slower than that of the machine you tested this on (since my computer is quite old). Anyway, it's a minor bug, I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

### Mirror for version 1.1

---

I couldn't download the .dmg file, the browser tells me that the server is unreachable, so I download the source code from github and made a "mirror", If you have the same issue you can alternatively download it at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jryzj1omtf5dq7t/Stack%20Exchange%20Notifier.dmg

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely unable to log in on a i5 MBP running 10.10.3 - the login window disappears before I can do anything.

I'm logged in to my SE account on every browser on my machine and assumed it was fetching my credentials that way, but no dice.

I've reinstalled the app twice, fwiw.

Comment: That probably means you're already logged in. Try "Invalidate login token" if you want to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I've been getting intermittent "Access denied" warning messages next to the "Check now" line. If I click on "Log in" the login window pops up, automatically logs itself in, and disappears, and everything updates. It seems like it happens about once a day -- is there some kind of 24-hour credential timeout?

It would be nice if the menu icon changed color to indicate that it had gotten an error, instead of me having to click on it to see the message.

Comment: And now this problem seems to have cleared up. I was away from home for a little over a day starting Saturday miorning, with my computer running the whole time. When I returned, I expected to see the "Access denied" message in the menu, but it was still happy, and hasn't reported an error yet since then.

Answer (score 0):

SE Notifier is crashing on me now. It was working fine this morning, but when I came back from lunch the menu icon was missing. I tried restarting it, the login window popped up, it filled itself in as usual and disappeared, and then the app crashed. Here's the beginning of the crash report file (it's too long to post everything):

```
Process:               Stack Exchange Notifier [11170]
Path:                  /Applications/Stack Exchange Notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/Stack Exchange Notifier
Identifier:            hewgill.com.Stack-Exchange-Notifier
Version:               1.1 (8)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Stack Exchange Notifier [11170]
User ID:               505

Date/Time:             2018-05-03 13:42:43.119 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G20015)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        2F846CD1-9441-91E4-768A-967C7910A47E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C8B67568-6E80-4443-BD61-A600DCE79C13

Time Awake Since Boot: 2300000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       800000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3c0452 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9136373c objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a42749d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff96a34f99 -[NSURL(NSURL) initWithString:relativeToURL:] + 102
4   Stack Exchange Notifier             0x0000000100002762 -[Stack_Exchange_NotifierAppDelegate resetMenu] + 1239
5   Stack Exchange Notifier             0x0000000100004d8b -[Stack_Exchange_NotifierAppDelegate connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 3132
6   CFNetwork                           0x00000001030cd391 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
7   CFNetwork                           0x00000001030cd2a6 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 233
8   CFNetwork                           0x00000001030cd1ab -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
9   CFNetwork                           0x00000001030d1f4a ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
10  CFNetwork                           0x000000010326707d ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff90b4240b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff90b50039 _dispatch_block_invoke + 474
13  CFNetwork                           0x00000001030cd068 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 24
14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a2f7d24 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
15  CFNetwork                           0x00000001030ccf61 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 137
16  CFNetwork                           0x00000001030cce02 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
17  CFNetwork                           0x00000001030ccc24 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a3557e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a334f0c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a33442f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8a333e28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8a99f935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
23  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8a99f76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
24  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff8a99f5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8a0df6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b8a0226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b894d80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b85e368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
29  Stack Exchange Notifier             0x00000001000018c8 start + 52

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
18446744020.891216 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e2c9f TCP Conn 0x1053b06a0 SSL Handshake DONE
18446744020.937138 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e2b7b TCP Conn 0x1053b06a0 starting SSL negotiation
18446744020.937313 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e1545 TCP Conn 0x1053b06a0 complete. fd: 30, err: 0
18446744020.937466 CFNetwork                    0x000000010316fe1f TCP Conn 0x1053b06a0 event 1. err: 0
18446744020.954365 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e0817 TCP Conn 0x1053b06a0 started
18446744020.968639 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896e11c [0x1068a5e00] Decoding completed without errors
18446744020.969593 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896c0fc [0x1068a5e00] Options: 2x-1 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 0001D060
18446744020.969593 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896bfae [0x1068a5e00] Decoding: C0 0x00300030 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 1705
18446744020.969593 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896b05e [0x1068a5e00] Created session
18446744020.969593 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896ba11 [0x1068a5e00] Releasing session
18446744020.971146 AppleJPEG                    0x00007fff9896b05e [0x1068a5e00] Created session
18446744020.987900 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e2c9f TCP Conn 0x1052b8180 SSL Handshake DONE
18446744020.992699 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e2c9f TCP Conn 0x1037b9450 SSL Handshake DONE
18446744021.044495 CFNetwork                    0x00000001030e2b7b TCP Conn 0x1052b8180 starting SSL negotiation

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff96953f06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff945234ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff864246df abort + 129
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff944c3b31 abort_message + 257
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff944e9e07 default_terminate_handler() + 267
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff91367491 _objc_terminate() + 103
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff944e6ffe std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff944e7073 std::terminate() + 51
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90b4241f _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90b50039 _dispatch_block_invoke + 474
10  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00000001030cd068 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 24
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a2f7d24 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
12  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00000001030ccf61 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 137
13  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00000001030cce02 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 282
14  com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00000001030ccc24 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 72
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a3557e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a334f0c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a33442f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8a333e28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a99f935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a99f76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8a99f5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b8a0df6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b8a0226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b894d80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8b85e368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
26  hewgill.com.Stack-Exchange-Notifier 0x00000001000018c8 start + 52
```

UPDATE 2018-10-18:

One of my notifications this morning was a "chat reply" that wa addressed to me:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47231762#47231762

This chat message occurred 20 minutes before the first crash. The problem apparently cleared up after I processed pending notifications. So maybe there's a bug regarding chat reply notifications. SENotifier already filters out notifications about edits; if it can't display chat notifications, it should filter them out as well.

Comment: And now this problem has cleared up all by itself.

Comment: This started happening again today.

Comment: And again it cleared up on its own.

Comment: Happened again today. It definitely looks like it's related to "chat reply" notifications, I got one this morning 20 minutes before the crash.