# OBSOLETE - ProStack Lite - Stack Overflow inbox notifier and quick accessor for OS X (in Mac App Store)

Tags: app, obsolete, notifier, mac-os-x, systemtray

## This product is discontinued.

The post about it is retained below for posterity.

---

> ## About
>
> Tired of manually checking Stackoverflow.com for new answers and comments?   Ever wished to access the new Stack Overflow questions
>   with one click?   ProStack Lite is the solution.
>
> ProStack Lite is a convenient menubar app for OS X. It notifies you of
>   new answers and comments from Stack Overflow, and provides quick access
>   to the Stack Overflow site. The best of all? The Lite version is free!
>   (Full version coming in October.)
>
> ## <del>Mac App Store link</del>
>
> <del>http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prostack-lite/id550852002?ls=1&mt=12</del>
>
> ## Screenshots
>
> [image: Monster screenshot 1]
>   [image: Monster screenshot 2]
>
> ## Feature Overview
>
> - Live icon that changes color when new answer or comment from Stack Overflow arrives *
> - One-click access to StackOverflow.com with the integrated web view
> - Open the current page in the browser
> - Enhanced for Retina displays
> - Multi-touch gestures for web view navigation (OS X 10.7+)
> - Automatically start with OS X
>
> (*) Due to the caching nature of the Stack Exchange API, the
>   notifications will arrive within a short delay of about two minutes.
>
> ## Contact
>
> If you have any PROBLEMS with ProStack Lite, please contact us at SUPPORT@LESSAPPS.NET ;)

Comment: This program sits and spins between authorizing and "returning to ProStack" messages.  OSX 10.8.2

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim yes, [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x). Not much activity on the github repo, but it's still working fine.

Comment: Hi, yes we are sorry to announce that ProStack is discontinued, due to poor sales and the newly-added browser support for native notifications. :( If you use Chrome, we recommend http://www.chimeapp.com/ as a replacement, before StackOverflow adds support for Native Push Notifications.