# Unread messages in inbox query shows older inbox messages

Tags: bug, inbox

I am using the `/inbox/unread` route to get the unread messages in a user's inbox. Recently (over the last couple of months, perhaps) I have noticed that the entries returned from this route initially reflect an *older* message in the inbox, that has already been read, perhaps quite some time ago. Sometime later (minutes?) the correct message will be returned. This happens even if there is more than one unread message in the inbox.

Is there something that has changed in the way unread messages are published that might cause this? I've tried this with both the 2.0 API, and after updating to use 2.1, but the problem remains.

Comment: I seem to be getting this behavior exclusively: my notifier always shows an old message that I've already read, never the latest one.