# `last_editor` is missing but `last_edit_date` is present?

Tags: support, questions, answers, editing, posts

Some posts (questions or answers) have a `last_edit_date` but no `last_editor`.  Does this *always* mean that the post was last edited by the post `owner`?

Example: [stackapps.com/a/3891/](https://stackapps.com/a/3891/11299)

---

PS: This issue came up on [pull-request 101 of the *stack-mode* project](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/pull/101).

Comment: https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode/pull/101

Comment: Pretty sure the last editor can be a deleted user who is not the OP. So the `last_editor` property would be blank/missing.  You'd have to run `/posts/{ids}/revisions` to be certain.

Comment: @BrockAdams That makes sense.  Do you know of a way I can find a live example?  Possibly the Data Explorer?

Comment: I've got a query going -- who knew I remembered so much SQL? (that is at least slightly tongue-in-cheek; even *I* know that this isn't a complex query.) http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/251122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last_editor` will be missing (empty) from the results when the last editor is a deleted user.  This deleted user does not have to be the owner, or original poster, of a given question or answer.

For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013671/331508) -- which [looks like this in the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#ids=27013671&filter=!SV_QVUCYzkf9gbTh0o&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

```
{
  "owner": {
    "user_id": 362168,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "display_name": "Saqueib"
  },
  "is_accepted": true,
  "score": 1,
  "last_activity_date": 1416395361,
  /*-- last_editor is enabled in the filter, but not returned because 
    the user was deleted.
  */
  "last_edit_date": 1416395361,
  "creation_date": 1416390599,
  "answer_id": 27013671,
  "question_id": 27013595
}
```

The owner is user 362168, while the last editor is a deleted user.

For more examples, see [this edit of Sean Allred's SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/251228/).

---

In the case of multiple deleted users, or to determine more information, use [the `/posts/{ids}/revisions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids).  Which [in this case gives](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=27013671&filter=!6J*A0qB17gtfb&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

```
{
  "user": {
    "user_type": "does_not_exist",
    "display_name": "user4269260"
  },
  ...
  "post_id": 27013671,
  "revision_type": "single_user",
  "revision_number": 5,
  "comment": "syntax edits",
  "revision_guid": "6C1F8C97-615C-4834-B9C5-881CB3F166E5"
},
{
  "user": {
    "user_id": 362168,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "display_name": "Saqueib"
  },
  ...
  "post_id": 27013671,
  "revision_type": "single_user",
  "revision_number": 4,
  "comment": "added 33 characters in body",
  "revision_guid": "C55616E3-4467-4240-8781-8ED91D006C1D"
},
```

Note that for revision_number 5, `user_id` is not present because deleted user's ids are removed (or hidden from us plebes).

It is for this same reason that `last_editor` is missing, because that is of type `user_id`.