# Security certificate error when logging in with myOpenID

Tags: support, api-v2, authentication

I have written [an application](https://stackapps.com/q/83) that embeds the [WebKit rendering engine](http://www.webkit.org) (the same rendering engine used in Safari and Chrome). This application makes use of the `/inbox` route and therefore requires the user's authorization. The application then displays the `/oauth/dialog` page which provides links for 5 different OpenID providers:

[image]

All of the providers (except myOpenID) work fine. However, as soon as a user clicks the myOpenID provider link, they receive the following message:

[image]

It should be noted that the error message is generated by my application and is not displayed by myOpenID. That being said, the SSL errors are indeed there (none of the other providers cause an error to appear).

The information for the certificate is as follows:

```
Common Name = *.myopenid.com
Subject Alternative Names = *.myopenid.com, myopenid.com
Issuer = StartCom Class 3 Primary Intermediate Server CA
Serial Number = 08C9
SHA1 Thumbprint = 8693F26F35126DFA2044E94C04A455F91515483C
Key Length = 2048 bit
Signature algorithm = SHA1+RSA (good)
Secure Renegotiation: Supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't control MyOpenId so we can't really do much about this, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I just thought I should let you know that the issue is there.